# postcss-svgo: TypeError: Cannot set property 'multipassCount' of undefined (Gatsby)

Tags: node.js, webpack, redhat, gatsby, postcss

On a Gatsby 2.17.6 project, when building:

> Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles [====
>   ]   1.940 s 1/6 17% run queries failed Building production JavaScript
>   and CSS bundles - 75.519s
>
> ERROR #98123  WEBPACK
>
> Generating JavaScript bundles failed
>
> **postcss-svgo: TypeError: Cannot set property 'multipassCount' of**
>   **undefined**
>
> not finished run queries - 77.639s npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno 1 npm ERR! gatsby-starter-default@1.0.0 build: node
>   node_modules/gatsby/dist/bin/gatsby.js build` npm ERR! Exit status 1

These are some of my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.8.0",
    :
    "gatsby": "^2.0.19",
    "gatsby-plugin-favicon": "^3.1.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "0.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.0.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.0.1",
    :
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^2.1.1",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.1"
  }
```

I don't see any configurations about postcss on gatsby-config.js, I guess it's a default behaviour of Gatsby. **npm ls postcss-svgo** throw this:

```
gatsby-starter-default@1.0.0 /<app>/source
└─┬ gatsby@2.17.6
  └─┬ optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin@5.0.3
    └─┬ cssnano@4.1.10
      └─┬ cssnano-preset-default@4.0.7
        └── postcss-svgo@4.0.2
```

I wouldn't mind to disable postcss-svgo if that's a solution, but I don't know how.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, coming in through `react-scripts@3.2.0` or `3.0.1` as the dependency from my project, also on Node 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Version 1.3.2 of svgo has been released, and [this bug is suposed to be fixed](https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/1180)**

So, it would be enough to remove your node_modules dir and package-lock.json file, and make a new *npm install* or *yarn install*

Anyway, thanks to other users suggesting to rollback svgo to 1.3.0

Answer (score 9):

my project is solved, use `npm install svgo@1.3.0 -E`, detail see: https://github.com/svg/svgo/issues/1174

Answer (score 5):

`"resolutions": { "svgo": "1.3.0" }`

Add the above to your "package.json" and then `rm -rf node_modules` to remove "node_modules" and then reinstall "node_modules" again.

This will resolve issue.
This issue is related to latest version of postcss-svgo.

Comment: Resolutions can only be used with yarn. In fact when I used yarn instead of npm (without the resolutions) the problem went away...

Answer (score -1):

It works.

- $ npm install -g svgo
- remove node_modules and package-lock.json
- $ npm install
- build project

Comment: It's really nop a good idea to do a global install here